# React native - Text input and Touchable opacity not working on android device

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am building this react native app, i have tested the app on numerous devices tablets/phones and works fine ex: samsung galaxy s20, all buttons, touchable opacitys and text inputs work fine.

But on this specific devices it fails, the devices are the following:

- Blackview Tab 8
- Huawei MatePad T

The app is going to be run on one of this devices, soo its mandatory that it works on those.

I found an error tracking the logs and tried to fix them but couldn't. I think the problem is that the onPress function of react native is not being fired when the buttons are clicked, you can see the logs below where i think the problem lies.

[image]

Here is the code where the problem seems to happen:

```js
<View style={styles.body_container}>

          <FlatList
            numColumns={2}
            keyExtractor={item => item.numero_socio}
            data={procura(Contas)}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={styles.lista_contas}>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button_icon}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('conta_consumo', {
                    conta: {
                      numero_socio: item.numero_socio,
                      nome_tuna: item.nome_tuna,
                      nome_completo: item.nome_completo,
                      email: item.email,
                      telemovel: item.telemovel,
                      valor_conta: item.valor_conta,
                      valor_maximo: item.valor_maximo
                    },
                    produtos: Produtos,
                    utilizador: utilizador
                  })}>
                    
                    <Icons 
                      estilo_alterado = {styles.conta_icon}
                      tipo = 'contas-icons' 
                      nome = {item.nome_tuna}
                      re_render = {true}
                    />
                  
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  
                  <Text style={styles.text_icon}>{item.nome_tuna.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                </View>
            )}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: Please confirm if the TouchableOpacity is imported from 'react-native' & not from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

Comment: Try using Pressable Instead of touchable Opacity

Comment: I have tried both this solutions. 

Importing TouchableOpacify from 'react-native' and from 'react-native-gesture-handler' does not work, and using Pressable instead also does not fix the issue.